# creat system call fail to set permissions

Tags: permissions, system-calls

I need to use `creat` system call to create file (it is used in legacy code and I'm not allowed to change this; example below is simplified one but the problem is just the same). I have the following code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main() 
{
    umask(0);
    int hndl = creat("abc.dat", S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP); // == 0660
    close(hndl);
}
```

File is created as expected (I checked the timestamp also), but the permissions are different from 0660:

```
$ gcc creat.c && ./a.out && ll | grep abc
-rwx---r-x 1 ulysses ulysses     0 May    7 19:42 abc.dat*
```

which are 0705. I tried to use 0660 literally and had the same result. Am I missing something?

Comment: Hm, this code should be working.  Are you sure the file didn't exist before calling `creat()`?  If it did, `creat()` will succeed and update the timestamp, but not change permissions.

Comment: @AndreasWiese oh, shame on me! After deletion it works just fine. Would you convert your comment to answer, so I'd be able to mark it read?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks correct and should do what you want.  You should check whether your program actually did *create* the file: if it did exist already, `creat()` would succeed without error and update the timestamp, but *not* change the permissions.